# How to identify the xpath for below html which is having text and link

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Please find my code below for HTML

```
<div class="content-table-pagination">
     Page             1                    
<a href="getSavedSearch.do?startsWith=20">2 </a>
<a href="getSavedSearch.do?startsWith=40">3 </a>
```

I've tried below code. to loop on pages.

```
List<WebElement> allrows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/div[3]/table/tbody/tr")); 

System.out.println("Total rows :" +allrows.size());

//Getting the page count

List<WebElement> allpages = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='content-table-pagination']//a")); 

System.out.println("Total pages :" +allpages.size());

for(int i=1; i<=(allpages.size()); i++)
{
  List<WebElement> allrows1 = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/div[3]/table/tbody/tr")); 
  for(int row=1; row<=allrows.size(); row++)
  {
   System.out.println("Total rows :" +allrows1.size()); 
   String validatorSoruceRefId = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='content']/div[3]/table/tbody/tr["+row+"]/td[7]")).getText();
   System.out.println(validatorSoruceRefId);
   System.out.println("Row loop");
   //if(validatorSoruceRefId==Constants.SourceRefId){
   if(validatorSoruceRefId.contains("MANTPLAP27102014090917528")){
       System.out.println("is it found");
        break;
      }
    else
      {
       System.out.println("Element doesn't exist");
       }
      allpages = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='content-table-pagination']//a"));
                     }
    driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    allpages.get(i).click();
    System.out.println("I'm in page number"+ i);
```

if I use this method to click on paination, it clicks only 1 and 3 pages.It skips the 2nd page.

`allpages.get(i).click();`

Help me on this

Comment: if your logic inside for loop is correct then it should click on the Page 2 hyperlink

Comment: logic is good.. but not clicking on get(i).click

Comment: do u get any exception

Comment: I increase the wait time, it's working fine now. Thanks Rishi.